# vim : toggle number with relativenumber

Tags: vim, vimrc

with

```
setl nu!
```

I can toggle number (on/off), similar with relativenumber

```
setl rnu!
```

how I can toggle {off,number,relativenumber} ?

Comment: aw. why on earth was this question migrated to SU? It is a _programming_ question related to a _prorgramming tool_. It doesn't get more SO than that. The programmers that focus on SO (like me) would now not be able to find this answer because 5 people don't know what vim is. Go figure. META: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: @sehe, I agree , this is a question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if &nu == 1
   set rnu
elseif &rnu == 1
   set nornu
else
   set nu
endif
```

Comment: thanks Benoit, I added your solution as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/1239808)

Comment: @JuanPablo: mmm. I like my version better :)

Comment: @sehe:  I'd say the same about my version. :-)

Answer (score 19):

Because I love a logic puzzle, and really love it when a vim command fits on a single line for succinct repeats (<kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> is a personal favourite):

```
:exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"
```

This will maintain the same cycle. I think it is mainly because `let &nu=1` will implicitly set norelativenumber - for reasons probably found in the documentation :)

Comment: +1 as I can place it in my .vimrc file as one line of `nmap <F3> :exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"<CR>` to toggle through three options using F3.

Comment: you could make that `nnoremap <silent> <F3>`... to reduce visual distraction and interfering with other mappings.

Comment: I came up with almost the same (but shorter :-) line when read the question: `exe'se'&nu+&rnu?'rnu!':'nu'`.

Comment: By the way, to assure yourself of the connection between `number` and `relativenumber` options, see `:helpg When setting this option`.

Comment: @ib: thanks for sharing. I really love your vim code golfs - there are gems in there that really speed up my everyday work; In this case, however, I have specificly selected my version (a net 3 characters longer - besides whtiespace cramp) because it is legible. In my view, there isn't any gain from condensing it further: it does get harder to type and a lot harder to remember even if you ever _had to_ type it from memory. This is going to be in a mapping. So Benoit's version is fine, except for it not fitting nicely on a single line

Comment: @ sehe: who is `ib` user? why don't have perfil ?

Comment: @juanpablo: as you must be aware, some parallel universe mishap defied logic and astrally projected his holy highness IB into a galaxy in which he actually doesn't exist. In other words: migrated

Comment: I like this version, but I find it obfuscated.

Comment: @Benoit , yes this version is more elegant, but maybe is confused for any vim user.

Comment: If the reason for this answer is to have a one-liner then you can do: `:if &nu == 1 | set rnu | elseif &rnu == 1 | set nornu | else | set nu | endif` ; then `@:` just works (I also use it a lot)

Comment: @Benoit: yeah I sort of got that. In that case, however, the if-else is no longer any more legible and I'd argue that my version is then more concise: the binary switch on 'se rnu!' or 'se nu!': it is instantly clear that one of the two is happening. Also, note (a) that I already argued that your version is _fine_ since it is just going to be a mapping, and (b) see the first sentence of my answer :) You could be preaching to the choir.

Comment: @sehe: I had not seen your previous comment. I agree that the if-else is not really legible on a single line (but IMO still more understandable than a golfed one!)

Comment: You think I golfed it? I just wrote what I wanted it to do :) Sorry that it comes out like that... it happens to me all the time (fyi: the brainwave that makes that happen is that I usually think: (bool)a!=(bool)b for XOR pretty quickly. Blame languages without XOR operator)

Answer (score 8):

For those who would like a more readable solution, the following is what I have in my .vimrc

```
" Relative or absolute number lines
function! NumberToggle()
    if(&nu == 1)
        set nu!
        set rnu
    else
        set nornu
        set nu
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-n> :call NumberToggle()<CR>
```

The cool thing about this is that you can hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> to toggle between relative and absolute number modes!

Answer (score 7):

As of Vim [7.3.1115](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/patches/7.3/7.3.1115) this has become a little more complicated to do.

The reason is that besides "no line numbers" and "absolute line numbers", there are now *two* settings for relative line numbers: ordinary "relative line numbers", and "relative line numbers with absolute number on the cursor line".

More technically speaking, all four  combinations of `'number'` and `'relativenumber'` are now possible.

Here's how to toggle:

- Toggle all four settings, ***no numbers*** → ***absolute*** → ***relative*** → ***relative with absolute on cursor line***:

  ```
  :exe 'set nu!' &nu ? 'rnu!' : ''
  ```
- Toggle between ***no numbers*** → ***absolute*** → ***relative***:

  ```
  :let [&nu, &rnu] = [&nu+&rnu==0, &nu]
  ```
- Toggle between ***no numbers*** → ***absolute*** → ***relative with absolute on cursor line***:

  ```
  :let [&nu, &rnu] = [!&rnu, &nu+&rnu==1]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative like *Eric Anderson* above:

```
"Relative with start point or with line number or absolute number lines
function! NumberToggle()
    if(&number == 1)
        set number!
        set relativenumber!
      elseif(&relativenumber==1)
        set relativenumber
        set number
      else
        set norelativenumber
        set number                                                  
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <C-n> :call NumberToggle()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
" put this in your .vimrc or source it from your .vimrc


  function! ToggleRelativeNumber()

      if &relativenumber

           set norelativenumber

      else

           set relativenumber

      endif

  endfunction

  nmap ;r :call ToggleRelativeNumber()<CR>
```